# laravel about inner join and subquery

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

ok, now ,I want get sql just like:

```
select field1,field2,field3  from orders

inner join  

(select id from orders where field4=3 limit 1000, 20)

as temp using(id)
```

how can I get this by laravel 5.1?

er, sorry I poor in english. What I mean is I want get the native sql like that , and now I don't know what can I do with laravel DB or ORM.  I create a model `Order` corresponding to the table `orders`.

thank you ~

Comment: Provide more details models & table structure

Comment: can you please provide join condition?

Comment: inner join it self

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although it is not a good way to do it because laravel supports inner joins in query builder. You can do it like this:

```
DB::select(DB::raw(" select field1,field2,field3  from orders
inner join  
(select id from orders where field4=3 limit 1000, 20)
as temp using(id)
"))->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code

```
DB::select(DB::raw(" select field1,field2,field3  from orders
    inner join  
    (select id from orders where field4=3 limit 1000, 20)
    as temp using(id)
    "))->get();
```